# Createjs.Bitmap(SVG) will scale like vector in Chrome, but like bitmap in Firefox

Tags: svg, easeljs

Helle everybody,
I recently started digging into Canvas and libraries. I chose EaselJs for a current project and I ran into a perculiar result.

This is what I made so far: [Test Page](http://s213926116.online.de/KeepCool/test2.html)

You can zoom in and out with the mouse wheel. When I do so in Chrome the image will behave like a vector although it is a createjs.Bitmap I created from a SVG.
In Firefox it won't, and I reckon that's how it's supposed to be. But it would be so very convenient if it did and it works just fine in Chrome for some reason.

I think performance-wise this would be a better solution than converting the SVG to a shapes with one of those converters which will produce a ton of javascript code, espescially since the shapes are quite sophisticated already.

Can anyone help?

Comment: It works in IE10 the same way as it works in Chrome. I don't understand what you're looking for here for help? It's possibly a Firefox issue somehow (either due to the file you're using, or something about the way it resizes images that contain SVG). Someone else may know whether this feature you're relying on is part of a specification or just "works that way".

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, the question is how I could get it to work on Firefox as well or if it is an issue with either Firefox or Chrome +IE (in case they were not supposed to do that), which meant I had to look into another solution.

Comment: I'd suggest it's a bug or unimplemented feature of Firefox. As I said, it may not be part of any standard, so it may never be supported officially. Or, maybe just load the SVG directly and add the zoom, etc. to that.

Comment: If you have the SVG in Illustrator, you can also take a look at the following workflow: http://tomkrcha.com/?p=3640

Comment: I am unable to check your example as the link in the question is now broken but it is worth noting that Firefox does not recognize `zoom` and uses `transform: scale();` (usually with `transform-origin: 0 0;` to keep the top left of the element in the same place).